# Undefined method 'order' - find_by_id + order DESC + first Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to find the highest bid on an auction. Within the auction controller I do the following: First I want to retrieve all bids of the Bid Model by the ID, then I want to order the results descending, and pick the first one (=should be the highest bid):

```
@highest_bid = Bid.find_by_auction_id(params[:id]).order("amount DESC").first
```

Throws this error:

```
NoMethodError in AuctionsController#show undefined method `order' for #<Bid:0x98e52e8>
```

Extracted source (around line #11):

```
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    @seller = User.find(@auction.user_id)
    @highest_bid = Bid.find_by_auction_id(params[:id]).order("amount DESC").first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `order` method only on [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) class, while `find_*` operation returns [ActiveRecord::Base](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) (`Bid`, in your case).

You should rewrite your query like this:

```
@highest_bid = Bid.where(auction_id: params[:id]).order("amount DESC").limit(1).first
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, as long as there are any bids. But If there are no bids on an auction I get: undefined method `amount' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #15):
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
          
   </p>
   <p>
   <strong>Highest Bid:</strong>
     <%= @highest_bid.amount %>
   </p>
   
   <h2>Bids</h2>

Comment: You should check @highest_bid.present? condition.

Comment: Isn't it better to call `.limit(1).first` instead of `.first?` This allows active-record to not have to order/load the whole search result database. It returns nil if there is no result.

Answer (score 1):

`find_by_auction_id` returns single `Bid` object, you can't call `order` on it. You should do:

```
@higheset_bid = @auction.bids.order('amount DESC').first
```

and you should create `has_many :bids` association in `Auction` model if you don't have this.